# Where should I put my Upstart scripts?

Tags: upstart

I'm trying to figure out Upstart and I'm not sure if I should put them in

```
/etc/init
```

or

```
~/.config/upstart
```

And what is the difference between the locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/init` is for [system jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-job) - those services which are started independent of any user being logged in. These are typically system services. By default, commands are run as root unless `setuid` is used.

`~/.config/upstart` is for [session jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) - these are run for a user logged into the GUI.

What does your Upstart job do?

- Is it performing some function for some logged in user, specific to them? Use `~/.config/upstart`.
- Does it not need a user logged in do its work, or need to run when the system starts? Use `/etc/init`.

Comment: I put a script in ~/.config/upstart/  but when I run "sudo service <service_name> start", it says "unrecognized service".  Do you know why this is?

Comment: @RyanStull the service command deals exclusively with system jobs and sysvinit scripts. Simply use `start service_name`, or `initctl start service_name`.